# Can't get Azure DevOps Release Pipelines to when I include Code Coverage

Tags: azure-devops

So I'm trying to set up a YAML for the new unified build and release pipelines, but running to problems when I publish code coverage results to the build...

The error I get, when I include code coverage reporting, is:

```
Job Job1: Step Download_Code Coverage Report_870 has an invalid name. Valid names may only contain alphanumeric characters and '_' and may not start with a number.
```

When I set it up like this, it works, but I don't get code coverage results:

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core
trigger:
  - master

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  system.debug: true

stages:
  - stage: BuildAndDeploy
    displayName: Test
    jobs:
      - job: Quality
        displayName: Get Test Coverage and Code Quality
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          # Install the latest version of the dotnet sdk
          - task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
            displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.2.103'
            inputs:
              version: 2.2.103

          - script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
            displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

          - script: dotnet test --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --logger trx --no-build
            displayName: 'dotnet test --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --logger trx --no-build'

          - task: PublishTestResults@2
            inputs:
              testRunner: VSTest
              testResultsFiles: 'test/**/*.trx'

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: Package Artifact
            inputs:
              command: 'publish'
              arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              zipAfterPublish: True
              publishWebProjects: true
              feedsToUse: 'select'
              versioningScheme: 'off'

          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
            inputs:
              artifactName: 'FakeApiServer'
              targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/FakeApi.Server.AspNetCore.zip'

  - stage: DeployTest
    dependsOn: BuildAndDeploy
    condition: and(succeeded(), not(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')))
    displayName: Deploy To Test
    jobs:
    - deployment: DeployToTest
      environment: Testing
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@1
              inputs:
                buildType: 'current'
                artifactName: 'FakeApiServer'
                targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              displayName: Deploy to https://fake-api-test.azurewebsites.com
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'Fake API Personal Azure Subscription'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'fake-api-test'
                Package: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/*.zip
                enableCustomDeployment: true
                DeploymentType: 'zipDeploy'

  - stage: DeployProd
    dependsOn: BuildAndDeploy
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    displayName: Deploy To Prod
    jobs:
    - deployment: DeployToProd
      environment: Production
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@1
              inputs:
                buildType: 'current'
                artifactName: 'FakeApiServer'
                targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              displayName: Deploy to https://fake-api.azurewebsites.com
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'Fake API Personal Azure Subscription'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'fake-api'
                Package: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/*.zip
                enableCustomDeployment: true
                DeploymentType: 'zipDeploy'
```

But when I include running and reporting code coverage, the deploy stage fails:

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core
trigger:
  - master

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  system.debug: true

stages:
  - stage: BuildAndDeploy
    displayName: Test
    jobs:
      - job: Quality
        displayName: Get Test Coverage and Code Quality
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          # Install the latest version of the dotnet sdk
          - task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
            displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.2.103'
            inputs:
              version: 2.2.103

          - script: dotnet tool install --global coverlet.console
            displayName: 'Install coverlet'

          - script: dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
            displayName: 'install reportgenerator'

          - script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
            displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

          - script: dotnet test --configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:Exclude="[xunit*]*" /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=\"opencover,cobertura\" --logger trx --no-build
            displayName: 'dotnet test --configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:Exclude="[xunit*]*" /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat="opencover,cobertura" --logger trx --no-build'

          - script: reportgenerator -reports:test/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:coveragereport -reporttypes:"HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura"
            displayName: 'reportgenerator -reports:test/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:coveragereport -reporttypes:"HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura"'

          - task: PublishTestResults@2
            inputs:
              testRunner: VSTest
              testResultsFiles: 'test/**/*.trx'

          - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
            displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
            inputs:
              codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
              summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coveragereport/Cobertura.xml'

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: Package Artifact
            inputs:
              command: 'publish'
              arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              zipAfterPublish: True
              publishWebProjects: true
              feedsToUse: 'select'
              versioningScheme: 'off'

          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
            inputs:
              artifactName: 'FakeApiServer'
              targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/FakeApi.Server.AspNetCore.zip'

  - stage: DeployTest
    dependsOn: BuildAndDeploy
    condition: and(succeeded(), not(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')))
    displayName: Deploy To Test
    jobs:
    - deployment: DeployToTest
      environment: Testing
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@1
              inputs:
                buildType: 'current'
                artifactName: 'FakeApiServer'
                targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              displayName: Deploy to https://fake-api-test.azurewebsites.com
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'Fake API Personal Azure Subscription'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'fake-api-test'
                Package: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/*.zip
                enableCustomDeployment: true
                DeploymentType: 'zipDeploy'

  - stage: DeployProd
    dependsOn: BuildAndDeploy
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    displayName: Deploy To Prod
    jobs:
    - deployment: DeployToProd
      environment: Production
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@1
              inputs:
                buildType: 'current'
                artifactName: 'FakeApiServer'
                targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              displayName: Deploy to https://fake-api.azurewebsites.com
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'Fake API Personal Azure Subscription'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'fake-api'
                Package: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/*.zip
                enableCustomDeployment: true
                DeploymentType: 'zipDeploy'
```

Again, the error I'm getting is:

```
Job Job1: Step Download_Code Coverage Report_870 has an invalid name. Valid names may only contain alphanumeric characters and '_' and may not start with a number.
```

I was at Build 2019 and talked to the Azure DevOps folks at their booth, and they seemed to think it was likely an error in the system, but I still haven't heard back from them, so I figured I would see if anyone here had any ideas.

The really weird part is I'm *never* telling it to download the code coverage report artifact... it's just deciding to download it all on it's own, and failing before it ever gets to the download pipeline artifact step I defined.

Comment: Example failing build at https://dev.azure.com/jmather0115/FakeAPI.Server.AspNetCore/_build/results?buildId=87

Comment: Additionally, even when it does work, I don't get the environment display they showed in the talk, but I suspect that might be I'm just not in the right group to actually preview that yet?

Comment: Adding to the woe it looks like there is a bug that is causing code coverage reports not to be packaged correctly.  I'm having this issue at the moment.  So even if you get past this bug, the code coverage report wont show in the Code Coverage tab
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10191

Answer (score 1):

You could try out the ReportGenerator extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Palmmedia.reportgenerator (at least is saves some build time as you do not need to install it during build)

Also I have encountered several build issues today and seems to be tied to the usage of vmImage set to 'ubuntu-latest'.

What I see happening is that on some builds the filesystem wil look like this:

```
/home/vsts/agents/2.150.3/d:\a/1/s/
```

Whereas it should be:

```
/home/vsts/work/1/s/
```

After switching to 'Ubuntu 16.04' it seems to be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue , but i think its related to deployment job , when i use standard job with the same steps - issue didn't appear. Also i have noticed that my deployment job run on Server agent even if  pool: vmImage: ubuntu-latest is configured